# Typeorm - migrations based on entities

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

So I am using typeorm with ormconfig.json.
Since `synchronize` cannot be used in production, how can I run the migrations based on entities?

my `ormconfig.json` file

```
{
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "backend-api",
    "synchronize": false,
    "logging": true,
    "migrationsRun": true,
    "entities": ["dist/entity/**/*.js"],
    "migrations": ["dist/migration/**/*.js"],
    "subscribers": ["dist/subscriber/**/*.js"],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
        "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
}
```

Also here is my only `Todo.ts` entity file

```
import {
    BaseEntity,
    Column,
    CreateDateColumn,
    Entity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Todo extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column('text')
    text: string;

    @Column('boolean', { default: false })
    completed: boolean;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Got the solution for this problem.

So my `ormconfig.json` needed a slight update,

```
{
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "backend-api",
    "synchronize": false,
    "logging": true,
    "migrationsRun": false,
    "entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
    "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
    "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
        "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
}
```

and i needed to install `ts-node` to compile the `ts` entity and migration files.

I created the below mentioned scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "entity:create": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm entity:create -n",
    "migrate:generate": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -n",
    "migrate:run": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run",
    "migrate:revert": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert",
    "schema:drop": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm schema:drop"
}
```

and in the order of the script.
The one thing I learned is you cannot simply crate an entity file and run `migration:generate` on it. You first need to create an entity based on `typeorm` cli. I don't know why, but for me once I started creating the entity using the cli everything fallen into place

Answer (score 0):

To run the migrations based on **entities**, you can generate the **migrations** files from your **entities** as said in the [TypeOrm documentation about generating **migrations**](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#user-content-generating-migrations).

> TypeORM is able to automatically generate **migration** files with schema changes you made.

Run this command specifying the name of the **migration** to generate the file:

```sh
typeorm migration:generate -n <MigrationName>
```

After it, you just need to run your **migrations** by using the CLI:

```sh
typeorm migration:run
```

A good practice is to use the `migrationsRun` parameter to your database configuration to run your **migrations** on start:

```js
migrationsRun: true,
```

Comment: while generating it is asking me to create one migration. but it does not pickup from entitiis

Comment: Did you specified the path to your entities and migrations in your database configuration ?

Comment: Is your database empty without any table ? TypeOrm is matching the difference between your entities and your database to generate the missing tables/columns

Comment: I have dropped the database and created another one, but still the same

Comment: Instead of dropping the tables manually, try to run `typeorm schema:drop`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229013/discussion-between-jithin-and-hugo-sohm).

Comment: while running the generate command i am getting an error like `No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
`

Comment: and then i tried to create one, but got an empty up and down function inside the migration file

Comment: it's not coming from the entities